# Оставить меню при смене страницы

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap4

Хочу оставить меню при смене страницы.
В каждую страницу `html` добавлять меню или можно обойтись как то аккуратно, без копипаста?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Title</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
 <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data- 
 target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria- 
 expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav w-100 justify-content-center">

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Галлерея</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Обо мне</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">События</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Наша Школа</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Нормативы</a>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>

<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group indent">
        <label class="sr-only"> </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="name">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group indent">
        <label for="examplepassword" class="sr-only">Пароль </label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="examplepassword" 
placeholder="password">
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-dark">Войти</button>

</form>

</nav>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" 
integrity="sha384- 
q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script 

 src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/
 umd/popper.min.js" 
integrity="sha384- 
ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script 
src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
integrity="sha384- 
ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Используйте шаблонизаторы

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Переименуйте файл в расширение php, меню вынесите в отдельный файл, также с расширением php.

И подключайте в главном файле с помощью этой конструкции `<?php require_once('menu.php'); ?>`,

главный файл переименуйте в `index.php`

при необходимости если не коррестная кодировка символов на сайте, создайте в корне файл `.htaccess` без имени, и добавьте в него строку `AddDefaultCharset utf-8`